# Binary Search Array Object

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, search, binary

I am using a binary search array for the first time and having troubles. I am pretty sure the issue is in the void FindMyObject. Any ideas? The binary portion is near the bottom. It is labeled. It runs with no errors so I believe that I am close. I have looked at several examples and this seems on, I don't 100% understand the logic yet. Any advice?

```
string[] myStrArray = new string[] { " I"," am"," a"," Stella"," Student" };
object[] myObjArray = new object[] { " You"," are"," a"," Great"," Learner" };

void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Binary Search Array
    Array.Sort(myStrArray);
    Array.Sort(myObjArray);
    Response.Write("<br/><br/>");

    PrintValues(myStrArray);
    PrintValues(myObjArray);

    object myStr = "Learner";
    FindMyObject(myStrArray, myStr);

    object myObj = "Stella";
    FindMyObject(myObjArray, myObj);     
}

void FindMyObject(Object[] myArr, object myObject)
{
    int myIndex = Array.BinarySearch(myArr, myObject);
    if (myIndex < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The object to search for ({0}) is not found. The next larger object is at index {1}.", myObject, myIndex);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The object to search for ({0}) is at index {1}.", myObject, myIndex);
    }      
}
```

Comment: I believe you accidentally swapped the assignments for myStr and myObj.

Comment: myObjArray must be sorted

Comment: @evhen14 He's calling `Array.Sort` to sort the arrays.

Comment: yea there is a sort? Where did I swap them?

Comment: When `myIndex < 0`, clearly the index of the next larger element is not `myIndex` (which is negative, and thus can't be an index). Try `~myIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

Your array initializer has a bunch of strings with spaces in front.  Your search strings do not have spaces, so will not be found.

<rant>
This would have been a lot simpler to answer if you hadn't included all the miscellaneous array manipulations.  It is always a good idea to reduce a problem to a minimum set of code required to reproduce the error, since doing so will very often help you to identify where the problem actually exists.
</rant>

Sorry, had to get that off my chest :P

Comment: There I cleaned it up. So I'll try removing the spaces?

Comment: Yes, the spaces are definitely important.  The two strings " Stella" and "Stella" are not the same, any more than the number 1234 is the same as the number 234.